# Android Filter ListView

Tags: android, listview, time

I need a little help with a problem that I have.I'm trying to get a specific part of a list view which I am using in my application.Here is what I have in my list view :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.plovdiv);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        ListView schedule = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pld_schedule);
        String TIME = "";
        ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

        HashMap<String, Object> hm; hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Log.i("Time","Hours : "+hours+" minutes : "+minutes);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "06:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "06:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "07:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "07:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "08:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "09:15");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "10:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "10:45");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "11:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "12:15");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "13:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "13:45");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "14:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "15:15");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "16:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "16:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "17:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "17:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "18:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "18:40");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "19:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "20:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "20:40");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "21:40");
        items.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TIME, "22:30");
        items.add(hm);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(  this, items, R.layout.main_listview,
                                                    new String[]{TIME}, new int[]{ R.id.text});


        schedule.setAdapter(adapter);
        schedule.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

I want to show the items in list view which are bigger as number from the current time.

**example** It's `10:30` now, so I want to show only the items which are after `10:30` as a value in my list view : `10:45` , `11:30` and etc. I've tried with

```
String time= hours+" : "+minutes;
adapter.getFilter().filter(time);
```

,but it's not doing what I want.

So any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The filtering process calls the `toString` method on each object in the list for matching. So your object's `toString()` should be returning the time string.

What you can do now is wrap your fields in a class and override its `toString()` where you'll return the time member.

Comment: :Please hel me i am also trapped in same problem